# How to define a user defined predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write the following constraint in Prolog, is it possible?

```
C1(x, y) :  isSU(x) ∧ isSU(y)
```

note that isSU is a user defined predicate which reads a configuration file, and checks whether its input parameter (here x or y) has a certain condition or not.
Actually my problem is that, I don't know how to define a user defined predicate in Prolog. The other thing is that I don't know how to use universal and existential quantifiers in a rule in Prolog.

Thanks for your answer.
Ali Davoudian

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog your constraint would be written that way:

```
c1(X, Y) :- isSU(X), isSU(Y).
```

And about the rest I would recommend reading a book. Here is good list of free books about Prolog programming: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info